# Css backgroundImage inside an input element

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Im trying to put an image insdie an Input element. I am using the backgroundImage property with the value: 'url(`http://localhost:3000/uploads/icons8-search (1).svg`)'

the url sits on the back-end folder on folder 'uploads'

I also can access the url above Ctrl+Click so the url is alright.

```
export function Navbar() {
    const userInfo = useContext(UserContext)
    console.log(userInfo)
    return <>
        <nav style={{ position: 'sticky', top: '0px', width: '100%', height: '6rem', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', margin: 'auto', backgroundColor: 'white', border: '0.1px solid grey' }}>
            <ul style={{ listStyleType: 'none', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', gap: '3em' }}>
                <li style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}><a style={{ fontSize: '2rem' }}>INSTAGRAM</a></li>
                <li style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}><input style={{ height: '50px', backgroundImage: 'url(`http://localhost:3000/uploads/icons8-search (1).svg`)' }} className='inputNavbar__displayNone' placeholder='Search' /></li>
                <li><HomeIcon style={{ height: '50px' }} /></li>
                <li><ChatBubbleOutlineIcon style={{ height: '50px' }} /></li>
                <li><AddCircleOutlineIcon style={{ height: '50px' }} /></li>
                <li><NearMeIcon style={{ height: '50px' }} /></li>
                <li><FavoriteBorderIcon style={{ height: '50px' }} /></li>
                <li>{userInfo?.media ?
                    <img style={{ height: '40px', width: '24px', border: '1px solid black', borderRadius: '40px' }} src={`${serverUrl}/${userInfo.media}`} /> :
                    <img style={{ height: '40px', width: '24px', border: '1px solid black', borderRadius: '40px' }} src={`${serverUrl}/uploads/search-grey-1.png`} />}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </>


}
```

I want it to be like in Instagram's navbar.

thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Why do you have back ticks for that url? Maybe that's causing an issue?

Comment: hey, I have tried different ways, it didnt work.